# Recording video in Android in round-robin output style

Tags: android, video, mediarecorder

Working on an Android app.

I need to record video continuously.

But the video files can only be N seconds long.

I have it working so far, and the files are being created properly. However, the time it takes to stop the MediaRecorder and start it back up again with a new file handle, I lose 2 seconds between stop/start.

Is there anything procedure-wise that I can do to mitigate this delay? I'm recording in mp4 format so I'm suspecting I can't just force a "move" on a file on the filesystem since the video needs to be packaged properly using the mp4 encoding.

Anyone know, roughly, how I might go about this?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever figure out this problem? I am facing the same issue too